# General epigraph form of optimization problem whose objective function is a sum of functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

If we have an optimization problem whose objective function is a sum of functions

$$\min_x \sum_i f_i(\mathbf{x}) \\
\text{subject to}\quad \left\{ \begin{aligned}
h_j(\mathbf{x})&\leq 0 \\
g_k(\mathbf{x}) &= 0 \end{aligned} \right.$$

what are the necessary conditions for writing this problem in the following epigraph form?

$$\min_{\mathbf{x},\, t_i} \sum_i t_i \\
\text{subject to}\quad \left\{\begin{aligned}
f_i(\mathbf{x}) &\leq t_i \\
h_j(\mathbf{x}) & \leq 0 \\
g_k(\mathbf{x}) &= 0 \end{aligned} \right.$$

Comment: Do you mean necessary conditions for equivalence? There are none. It's always possible.

Comment: @MichaelGrant yes, I meant that. great thanks. Do you have any proof on this?

Comment: The way you prove it is this: you prove:  (1) if $x$ is feasible for model 1, it is feasible for model 2. (2) if $x$ is feasible for model 2, it is feasible for model 1. (3) if $x$ is optimal for model 1, it is optimal for model 2. (4) if $x$ is optimal for model 2, it is optimal for model 1.
That's it, really

Comment: Oh wait---you have strict inequality in one and non-strict in the other. I hope you didn't intend that

Comment: @MichaelGrant It was just a mistake. I corrected it.